# Storage of Unicode Characters in MySql and Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle, unicode, utf-8

Scenario: A database in MySql and Oracle. Both have same table and same columns. In one of the table I have a Column, 'FullName'.

Oracle Datatype used is VarChar2(64).
MySql Datatype used is VarChar(64).

To Support Unicode Character UTF 8 is used as the default character set.

I'm getting a  error in Oracle, which says "value too large for column", where as in MySql it works fine.

I would like to know, what's the difference between these two dbases?

Note: For japanese Character in UTF 8 encoding take 3 bytes.

Thanks in Advance.

Pavan

Comment: In Oracle, is the column declared as `VARCHAR2(64 BYTE)` or `VARCHAR2(64 CHAR)`?

Comment: CREATE TABLE "DUMMYUSER" 
   (
 .
 .
 .
 "FULL_NAME" VARCHAR2(64),
 .
 . 
 .
   ) ;

Comment: Thanks to Jeffery Kemp for asking this question. Gave me a completely new perspective to look a the problem...found the solution to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it was working in MYSQL is because VarChar(64) in MYSQL means, 64 characters and the default character is UTF8.

For oracle it was not working, although the default Character Set for Oracle was UTF8. Reason is VarChar2(64), means 64 bytes. And For japanese Character in UTF 8 encoding take 3 bytes for a single character. Hence the error "value too large for column".

Thank to David Sykes for the solution in  the following link.

[Difference between BYTE and CHAR in column datatypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81448/difference-between-varchar211-byte-and-varchar211-char)