# alter the size of column in table containing data

Tags: sql, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a varchar2 field shorter in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404194/how-to-make-a-varchar2-field-shorter-in-oracle)

In Oracle(9i and above)

```
 Alter table employee  
 MODIFY ename varchar2(10);
```

I want to alter the column ename of table employee from varchar2(30) to varchar2(10)

- Case1 : if the table has data having ename column containing values which are of length less than 10 char(i mean it can fit in varchar2(10) comfortably) - is this allowed by oracle ?
- Case 2: if the table has data having ename column containing values which are of length greater than 10 char(i mean it can not fit in varchar2(10)) - is this not allowed by oracle ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the question is.  What would you want to happen to an employee that has a 20 byte `ENAME` value if you try to decrease the size of the column to `VARCHAR2(10)`?  Do you want to truncate the data after the 10th byte?

Comment: Appears similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404194/how-to-make-a-varchar2-field-shorter-in-oracle/8404240#8404240

Comment: @Justin Cave... yes I do not have any problem with that ......as this is obvious that if i change the size to varchar2(10)...data will be truncated for ENAME having 20 byte...will oracle give some type of warning for this alter or will do it

Comment: No, you cannot have data greater than the size of a column in a column. What is the point otherwise? If you do have data greater than the size  of the columns why do you want to decrease it?

Comment: @jain007:i think link mentioned by `XQBERT` cater your problem ,first update all column having data more than 10 byte to 10 byte ,and then alter you're column.

Comment: @ Gaurav...what is mentioned by Bob in the below post is also right...that it will give an error.....right?
And what i understood is if i want to apply this case 2 successfully then i have to follow what xQbert says.....i.e first update all columns having data more than 10 byte

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Case 1 : Yes, this works fine.

Case 2 : This will fail with the error ORA-01441 : cannot decrease column length because some value is too big.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: ...and if i need the case 2 to work, then will i need to follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404194/how-to-make-a-varchar2-field-shorter-in-oracle/8404240#8404240 by xQbert

Comment: Yes - you'll need to truncate any values which are greater in length than the size to which you'll shrink the column.

Comment: Or better, study the impact of truncate that data. If you can make a process that would leave the information as rich as before, do it. For example, converting key words into short version of them. e.g: Example -> e.g. Dropping information is not good if didn't studied the impact.