# how to modify the size of a column

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, alter-table

I created the table Test_Project2 in Oracle SQL Developer. After that I realized that the column proj_name is of a small size, so I decided to modify the column using the follwoing statement

```
ALTER TABLE TEST_PROJECT2 MODIFY proj_name VARCHAR2(300);
```

but for some reason Oracle SQL Developer underscores the semi-colon with red and I do not what is mistake and how to correct it

**Test_Project2**:

```
CREATE TABLE Test_Project2 (
proj_id number(30),
proj_name VARCHAR2 (30),
proj_desc VARCHAR2(300)
);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179217/alter-the-size-of-column-in-table-containing-data

Comment: i solved it..it should be: ALTER TABLE Test_Project2 MODIFY (proj_name varchar(150));
/

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Regardless of what error Oracle SQL Developer may indicate in the syntax highlighting, actually running your `alter` statement exactly the way you originally had it works perfectly:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST_PROJECT2 MODIFY proj_name VARCHAR2(300);
```

You only need to add parenthesis if you need to alter more than one column at once, such as:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST_PROJECT2 MODIFY (proj_name VARCHAR2(400), proj_desc VARCHAR2(400));
```

Comment: I prefer to to add "CHAR" with varchar2 after the number, to avoid ambiguity with "BYTE": `ALTER TABLE TEST_PROJECT2 MODIFY proj_name VARCHAR2(300 CHAR);`. See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477564/varchar2n-bytechar-default-char-or-byte

Answer (score 14):

If you run it, it will work, but in order for SQL Developer to recognize and not warn about a possible error you can change it as:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST_PROJECT2 MODIFY (proj_name VARCHAR2(300));
```

Answer (score 13):

This was done using Toad for Oracle 12.8.0.49

```
ALTER TABLE SCHEMA.TABLENAME 
    MODIFY (COLUMNNAME NEWDATATYPE(LENGTH)) ;
```

For example,

```
ALTER TABLE PAYROLL.EMPLOYEES 
    MODIFY (JOBTITLE VARCHAR2(12)) ;
```