# Migrate tables with special characters in Talend studio

Tags: oracle, special-characters, talend

I am migrating from table A (DB A) to table B (DB B), an error occurs on 1 specific field that contains french characters (é, à, ..) and special characters (&, ', ..):

*Exception in component tOracleOutput_1
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12899: value too large for column "DB1"."COLUMN1"."COMMENT" (actual: 121, maximum: 118)*

While querying the table from sql editor, the maximum length for the values is 100.

How can I insert these values into the new table without loosing the special and the french characters?

Comment: compare `nls_language`&`nls_territory` parameters in `DB A` and `DB B`, and set `DB B`'s those values as `DB A`'s.

Comment: They have the same NLS_LANGUAGE and NLS_TERRITORY

Comment: The 2 DBs have different NLS_CHARACTERSET, DB A has WE8MSWIN1252 and DB B has AL32UTF8.
_Standard ASCII characters require 1 byte of storage space under in WE8(...) and in AL32UTF8, however, other characters require only 1 byte of storage space in WE8(...), but they require 2 or 
more bytes of space in AL32UTF8._ What do you think @BarbarosÖzhan ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not due to the special characters. Your column is too small.
You have three possibilities :

- Increase the size of your column directly in the table schema.
  See here: 
  [how to modify the size of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39785471/how-to-modify-the-size-of-a-column)
- Delete blank character before and after the value with the TRIM function in the tMap: `StringHandling.TRIM(row1.yourcolumn)`
- Truncate the value to fit the column in your tMap: `StringHandling.LEFT(row1.yourcolumn,118)` (your column have 118 characters max)