# Do I have to consider the bytes of the data to be saved on my database design?

Tags: oracle, encoding

Suppose I have four Chinese Traditional characters encoded using GB18030 (a 4-octet (bytes) encoding scheme), can this be saved in my database (Oracle) in a nvarchar field with length = 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the size of column by byte or by char so for your case 4 byte will be sufficient m for more info check this question:
[Difference between BYTE and CHAR in column datatypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81448/difference-between-byte-and-char-in-column-datatypes)