# Oracle VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) vs VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)

Tags: sql, oracle

If I want to pass values such as Sylvie Doré to a column in Oracle will I need to configure my columns as VARCHAR2(20 CHAR) as special characters such as é take up more than one byte?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81448/difference-between-byte-and-char-in-column-datatypes/81492#81492

Comment: Have you tried inserting 'ééé' into a varchar2(3 byte) and a varchar2(3 char) to see if they work?