# how many chars can a str contain?

Tags: sql, oracle

Good morning,
I have a problem in plsql because I have to know how many char a str can contain(I use  oracle 11).
The code in plsql is this:

```
str VARCHAR2(32767):= NULL;
```

str is a string of maximum size 32767 byte.

But what is the max number of characters which this string can  contain?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits001.htm

Comment: So, you want to know how many characters fit in 32767 bytes? That depends on the encoding of the characters.

Comment: I think that it depends on the Encoding system you're using.

Comment: I would think this question might already have an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81448/difference-between-byte-and-char-in-column-datatypes

Answer (score 3):

I noticed your question was about the number of char you can store, not the number of bytes. The difference is here (see SO answer [Difference between BYTE and CHAR in column datatypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81448/difference-between-byte-and-char-in-column-datatypes/81492#81492)):

Let us assume the database character set is UTF-8, which is the recommended setting in recent versions of Oracle. In this case, some characters **take more than 1 byte to store in the database**.

If you define the field as **VARCHAR2(11 BYTE)**, Oracle can use **up to 11 bytes** for storage, but you may not actually be able to store 11 characters in the field, because some of them take more than one byte to store, e.g. non-English characters.

By defining the field as **VARCHAR2(11 CHAR)** you tell Oracle it can use enough space to store **11 characters**, no matter how many bytes it takes to store each one. A single character may require up to 4 bytes.

Sample about the difference between chars and bytes: http://mothereff.in/byte-counter

Also, that character length semantics do not affect the **4000 byte maximum** (Oracle 11g, see doc [Oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits001.htm)) length for a VARCHAR2. Declaring a VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR) will allow fewer than 4000 characters if some of the characters require multiple bytes of storage.

Comment: Do you think you should have included attribution to [the answer you copied this from](http://stackoverflow.com/a/81492/266304)?

Comment: Alex, my mistake, I added the reference. Should I have used duplicate in that case, as I added info linked to the Oracle version he mentioned and the test showing the difference between char count and byte length

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure the question is an exact duplicate as it's specifically about hitting the 32k limit, I think, and the behaviour at that point.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/datatypes.htm#LNPLS311) (v11.2) **varchar2** has maxsize respectively:

- **PL/SQL**: 32767 bytes
- **SQL**: 4000 bytes in SQL.

To be sure that, independently by character set, you store N charge, you have to specify:

```
str VARCHAR2(32767 CHAR):= NULL;
```

By the way the number of bytes needed to store a character will depend upon the character set.

Starting from [version 12.1](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/12c/extended-data-types-12cR1.php), VARCHAR2 is extended to 32767 bytes.

Comment: You might add as a that in version 12c SQL VARCHAR2 length is possible to extend to 32,767 bytes.

Comment: `VARCHAR2(32767 CHAR)` doesn't mean you can have 32k multi-byte characters though; you're still limited to the overall 32k byte limit for the data type. For smaller sizes it makes a difference, e.g. `VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)` would allow 100 multi-byte characters so total storage may be more than 100 bytes; but not right at the top of the data type limit.