# What does it mean when the size of a VARCHAR2 in Oracle is declared as 1 byte?

Tags: sql, oracle, varchar, sqldatatypes

I know that I can declare a **`varchar2`** using the number of the characters that it should be able to contain.

However, in an `Oracle` database on which I am working, I found that a field (named PDF) is defined as follows:

```
VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)
```

What does this mean? How many characters can it contain?

Another, related question: What is the difference between a **`VARCHAR`** and a **`VARCHAR2`**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between varchar and varchar2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171196/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-varchar2)

Comment: and possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81448/difference-between-byte-and-char-in-column-datatypes

Comment: see also NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS parameter: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:29518831139714

Comment: I think in your case the difference between BYTE and CHAR is meaningless. Oracle does not support Boolean type so it is usually implemented as `CHAR(1)`. Having variable length string having max. length of one byte is non-sense.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can declare columns/variables as varchar2(n CHAR) and varchar2(n byte).

n CHAR means the variable will hold n characters. In multi byte character sets you don't always know how many bytes you want to store, but you do want to garantee the storage of a certain amount of characters.

n bytes means simply the number of bytes you want to store.

varchar is deprecated. Do not use it.
[What is the difference between varchar and varchar2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171196/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-varchar2)

Comment: Probably historic. At first a character was a byte. Then multi-byte characters where introduced and the meaning of the length was suddenly open to multiple interpretations.

Comment: I find it strange that when declaring a data type to store text characters, you are given the choice to specify the number of storage bytes.
The underlying storage size needs to be handled transparently by the db engine based on the corresponding text encoding.
If for example, as a user I need to store X number of text characters using UTF-8 encoding, a DB engine needs to figure out internally how much storage is needed for that. Letting a user set that is opening the door for trouble.

Comment: There's a database parameter NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS that takes care of that.

Answer (score 29):

The `VARCHAR` [datatype](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1822) is synonymous with the `VARCHAR2` datatype. To avoid possible changes in behavior, always use the `VARCHAR2` datatype to store variable-length character strings.

If your database runs on a single-byte character set (e.g. `US7ASCII`, `WE8MSWIN1252` or `WE8ISO8859P1`) it does not make any difference whether you use `VARCHAR2(x BYTE)` or `VARCHAR2(x CHAR)`.

It makes only a difference when your DB runs on multi-byte character set (e.g. `AL32UTF8` or `AL16UTF16`). You can simply see it in this example:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    VARCHAR2_byte VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    VARCHAR2_char VARCHAR2(1 CHAR)
);

INSERT INTO my_table (VARCHAR2_char) VALUES ('€');
1 row created.

INSERT INTO my_table (VARCHAR2_char) VALUES ('ü');
1 row created.

INSERT INTO my_table (VARCHAR2_byte) VALUES ('€');
INSERT INTO my_table (VARCHAR2_byte) VALUES ('€')
Error at line 10
ORA-12899: value too large for column "MY_TABLE"."VARCHAR2_BYTE" (actual: 3, maximum: 1)

INSERT INTO my_table (VARCHAR2_byte) VALUES ('ü')
Error at line 11
ORA-12899: value too large for column "MY_TABLE"."VARCHAR2_BYTE" (actual: 2, maximum: 1)
```

`VARCHAR2(1 CHAR)` means you can store up to 1 character, no matter how many byte it has. In case of Unicode one character may occupy up to 4 bytes.

`VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)` means you can store a character which occupies max. 1 byte.

If you don't specify either `BYTE` or `CHAR` then the default is taken from `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` session parameter.

Unless you have Oracle 12c where you can set `MAX_STRING_SIZE=EXTENDED` the limit is `VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)`

**However**, `VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)` does not mean you are guaranteed to store up to 4000 characters. The limit is still 4000 **bytes**, so in worst case you may store only up to 1000 characters in such field.

See this example (`€` in UTF-8 occupies 3 bytes):

```
CREATE TABLE my_table2(VARCHAR2_char VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR));

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO my_table2 VALUES ('€€€€€€€€€€');
    FOR i IN 1..7 LOOP
        UPDATE my_table2 SET VARCHAR2_char = VARCHAR2_char ||VARCHAR2_char;
    END LOOP;
END;
/

SELECT LENGTHB(VARCHAR2_char) , LENGTHC(VARCHAR2_char) FROM my_table2;

LENGTHB(VARCHAR2_CHAR) LENGTHC(VARCHAR2_CHAR)
---------------------- ----------------------
                  3840                   1280
1 row selected.


UPDATE my_table2 SET VARCHAR2_char = VARCHAR2_char ||VARCHAR2_char;

UPDATE my_table2 SET VARCHAR2_char = VARCHAR2_char ||VARCHAR2_char
Error at line 1
ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
```

See also [Examples and limits of BYTE and CHAR semantics usage (NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS) (Doc ID 144808.1)](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/144808_1.html)

Answer (score 7):

To answer you first question:
Yes, it means that 1 byte allocates for 1 character. Look at this example

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> create table test (id number(10), v_char varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values(11111111111,'darshan');
insert into test values(11111111111,'darshan')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allows for this column


SQL> insert into test values(11111,'darshandarsh');
insert into test values(11111,'darshandarsh')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12899: value too large for column "SYS"."TEST"."V_CHAR" (actual: 12,
maximum: 10)


SQL> insert into test values(111,'Darshan');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

And to answer your next one:
The difference between `varchar2` and `varchar` :

1. `VARCHAR` can store up to `2000 bytes` of characters while `VARCHAR2` can store up to `4000 bytes` of characters.
2. If we declare datatype as `VARCHAR` then it will occupy space for `NULL values`, In case of `VARCHAR2` datatype it will `not` occupy any space.

Answer (score 4):

it means ONLY one byte will be allocated per character - so if you're using multi-byte charsets, your 1 character won't fit

if you know you have to have at least room enough for 1 character, don't use the BYTE syntax unless you know exactly how much room you'll need to store that byte

when in doubt, use VARCHAR2(1 CHAR)

same thing answered here [Difference between BYTE and CHAR in column datatypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81448/difference-between-byte-and-char-in-column-datatypes)

Also, in 12c the max for varchar2 is now 32k, not 4000. If you need more than that, use CLOB

in Oracle, don't use VARCHAR

Comment: *Also, in 12c the max for varchar2 is now 32k, not 4000.* Yes, but it needs to be setup explicitly at `SYSTEM` level by making `MAX_STRING_SIZE` to `EXTENDED`, else by default it would be `4000`.

Comment: It works also for multi-byte charsets, as long as the character uses only one byte, e.g. up to `CHR(127)` in UTF-8