# How do I grant CLOB privileges to a foreign queue user in Oracle Advanced Queuing?

Tags: oracle, oracle-aq

We grant the following priviliges on schema A to user B for inserting into a queue in Oracle 12c:

```
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO &UNAME_ENQUEUE;
GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.DBMS_AQ TO &UNAME_ENQUEUE;
GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.DBMS_AQADM TO &UNAME_ENQUEUE;
GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.DBMS_AQIN TO &UNAME_ENQUEUE;
GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.DBMS_AQJMS TO &UNAME_ENQUEUE;

...

    DBMS_AQADM.GRANT_QUEUE_PRIVILEGE (
            privilege        =>    'ENQUEUE',
            queue_name       =>    v_queue_name,
            grantee          =>    v_grantee_name,
            grant_option     =>    FALSE);
```

The queue table is defined as:

```
dbms_aqadm.create_queue_table(queue_table => 'queue_name_t', queue_payload_type => 'sys.aq$_jms_message');

...

GRANT INSERT ON &USERNAME..queue_name_t TO &UNAME_ENQUEUE;
GRANT SELECT ON &USERNAME..queue_name_t TO &UNAME_ENQUEUE;
```

The queue is accessed through the JMS interface. We noticed that for messages with a size greater than x, Oracle wants to store the message payload as a CLOB. First of all, we do not know x. Guessing from [the Specification of the JMS message type](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/t_jms.htm#ARPLS71803), it should be 4000 for text messages and 2000 for byte messages, as smaller messages would fit into `text_vc` or `bytes_raw`. However, the payload is only about 500 characters long. (We do set a couple of headers, but those go into a separate header 'field', if I understand the type correctly).

The main problem however is that we get the error `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges` when user B wants to insert a CLOB sized message into schema A. Authorized as user A the problem does not arise.

1. How can we grant the necessary privileges to user B?
2. When does Oracle choose to use a (C)LOB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1. How can we grant the necessary privileges to user B?*

Please provide more extensive exception stack for `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges` this message doesn't say much about the root cause
Here are my thoughts.

In Oracle DB there's a precondition for the enqueue of JMS types like sys.aq$_jms_message
Try enabling it for your queue.

```
begin
dbms_aqadm.enable_jms_types(queue_table => v_queue_name);
end;
/
```

btw. Payloads with LOBs require explicit Select, Insert and Update privileges on the queue table

*2.When does Oracle choose to use a (C)LOB?*

No need to guess from docs. Payload type that you use for your queue stores text message either in text_vc or in text_lob variable. You wrote `the payload is only about 500 characters long`, and as you can see on the type definition field is declared as varchar2(4000) which doesn't necessarily mean it's about characters, it can be about bytes as well - when there's no explicit declaration it's determined by the nls param (see also [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30865064/what-does-it-mean-when-the-size-of-a-varchar2-in-oracle-is-declared-as-1-byte))
`select * from V$NLS_PARAMETERS t where t.PARAMETER = 'NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS';`

For aq$_jms_text_message there are 2 options, either you provide large object datatype as an input param, or your message >= 4000 and that's why Oracle stores it as a clob.
Similar situation is for aq$_jms_bytes_message (payload IN RAW if the length of bytes_lob is =< 32767 vs payload IN BLOB )

```
SYS.AQ$_JMS_MESSAGE (
  text_vc       varchar2(4000),
  text_lob      clob,
...

  -- set_text sets payload in varchar2 into text_vc if the length of
  -- payload is <= 4000, into text_lob if otherwise.
  MEMBER PROCEDURE set_text ( payload IN VARCHAR2 ),
..
  --
  -- set_text sets payload in clob in text_lob.
  MEMBER PROCEDURE set_text ( payload IN CLOB ),
...
)
```

btw. there are also methods like DBMS_AQADM.ENABLE_DB_ACCESS for Agents using HTTP protocols and secure queues, maybe it's worth checking this

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, the UPDATE privilege was missing for the user and appears to be relevant when inserting a CLOB or LOB message.