sql extraction of identification numbers
Hi i got the following cases:
i need to extract from each ID format the correct numbers depending on the case

09N 0720001536 should be cleaned to: 97201536
08N 0798001682 should be cleaned to: 87981682
08NT0184001825 should be cleaned to: 81841825
05NT0702001350 should be cleaned to: 57021350
08  0732001283 should be cleaned to: 87321283
00E 0008138007 should be cleaned to: E8138007
10  0732001283 should be cleaned to: 107321283
10N 0798001682 should be cleaned to: 107981682
10NT0702001350 should be cleaned to: 107021350

all cases works except one 6. 00E 0008138007 should be cleaned to: E8138007, right now its cleaning to E813800 so the last number is left, im not sure what im doing wrong in the SP as i see it correctly, any idea of what im missing?
thank you
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE AGAITAN_PROCESAR_CEDULA (
    p_cedula IN VARCHAR2,
    p_resultado OUT VARCHAR2
) AS
    v_provincia VARCHAR2(2);
    v_bloque3 VARCHAR2(4);
    v_bloque4 VARCHAR2(6);
    v_cedula_limpia VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
    -- Paso 1: Limpiar la cédula, manteniendo solo números y la letra 'E'
    v_cedula_limpia := REGEXP_REPLACE(p_cedula, '[^0-9E]', '');

    -- Paso 2: Extraer la provincia
    v_provincia := SUBSTR(v_cedula_limpia, 1, 2);

    -- Paso 3: Extraer los bloques
    v_bloque3 := SUBSTR(v_cedula_limpia, 3, 4);  -- Tercer bloque (dígitos 3 a 6)
    v_bloque4 := SUBSTR(v_cedula_limpia, 7, 6);  -- Cuarto bloque (dígitos 7 a 12)

    -- Paso 4: Manejo de casos específicos
    IF v_cedula_limpia LIKE '00E%' THEN
        -- Caso especial: Si la cédula es de tipo '00E'
        p_resultado := 'E' || LTRIM(v_bloque4, '0');  -- Mantener la letra E y limpiar el bloque 4
    ELSE
        -- Limpiar ceros a la izquierda en la provincia
        v_provincia := LTRIM(v_provincia, '0');

        -- Limpiar ceros a la izquierda en los bloques
        v_bloque3 := LTRIM(v_bloque3, '0');
        v_bloque4 := LTRIM(v_bloque4, '0');

        -- Formar la cédula limpia
        p_resultado := v_provincia || v_bloque3 || v_bloque4;
    END IF;

    -- Asegurarse de que el resultado no esté vacío
    IF p_resultado IS NULL OR p_resultado = '' THEN
        p_resultado := '0';  -- O un mensaje adecuado
    END IF;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        p_resultado := NULL; -- En caso de error, devolver NULL
END AGAITAN_PROCESAR_CEDULA;
/


case 6. 00E 0008138007 should be cleaned to: E8138007, right now its cleaning to E813800
block 4 debug:
    Block 4 value: 1536
09N 0720001536 Case 1: 97201536
Block 4 value: 1682
08N 0798001682 Case 2: 87981682
Block 4 value: 1825
08NT0184001825 Case 3: 81841825
Block 4 value: 1350
05NT0702001350 Case 4: 57021350
Block 4 value: 1283
08  0732001283 Case 5: 87321283
00E 0008138007 Case 6: E813800
Block 4 value: 1283
10  0732001283 Case 7: 107321283
Block 4 value: 1682
10N 0798001682 Case 8: 107981682
Block 4 value: 1350
10NT0702001350 Cédula limpia 9: 107021350

Statement processed.


SUBSTR(v_cedula_limpia, 7, 6)   limits you to 6 characters when you need 7 for 8138007 .

@BartMcEndree should i use 7,7 ? or something like that?

Please tag your RDBMS, see here why that's important: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

@BartMcEndree done, thank you for that

Please [edit] the question and explain (in English, not code) what the logic is that converts the input to the output. At the moment we either need to guess what the logic is from the output or try to reverse engineer your code (but your code is giving the wrong answer so it is unclear how helpful that would be).

Try
SUBSTR(v_cedula_limpia, 7) 

If substring_length is omitted, then Oracle returns all characters to the end of char. This should help you get more than 6 digits from the 4th block.

yeah i tried that but got empty answer when i use this for debug:
AGAITAN_PROCESAR_CEDULA('00E 0008138007', v_cedula_limpia);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('00E 0008138007 Cédula limpia 6: ' || v_cedula_limpia);


also tried that with 7 alone but still blank response, its very strange

You might want to add some debug output lines to see what your variable values are at each step. For example: DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Paso 4:'||:v_bloque4||' is the new block 4 value');

Got it i will try that debug for block4

just added in the op the debug of block 4, it shows all except that one of the case 6

That tells you that your debug line is not hit for case 6. This might be due to an error that was encountered and handled by the exception handler. I suggest you enhance your error handler to report more details.

i put the debug earlier and i got this Block 4 value: 813800 ///
00E 0008138007 Case 6: E813800

got this: Cleaned ID: 00E0008138007 Province: 00 Error occurred: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small 00E 0008138007 Case 6: 

works good  v_bloque4 VARCHAR2(7);  i just added more to this varchar, ty for your support!

I am not sure why that fixed your problem. At no point did you try to put more then 6 chrs into v_bloque4.

not sure but i increased  these vars   v_provincia VARCHAR2(3);
v_bloque3 VARCHAR2(5);
v_bloque4 VARCHAR2(7);
v_cedula_limpia VARCHAR2(20); and its working good

This explains it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30865064/what-does-it-mean-when-the-size-of-a-varchar2-in-oracle-is-declared-as-1-byte

good information, thank you again for the support and understanding

The logic you appear to be using is:

Remove all the characters that are not digits or E.
Remove the sub-string of the last 6 characters and trim any leading zeroes from it.
Remove the sub-string of then next last 4 characters and trim any leading zeroes from it.
Take the sub-string of the remaining characters from the start of the string and trim any leading zeroes from it.
Concatenate those 3 sub-strings in their original order.

You can use:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE AGAITAN_PROCESAR_CEDULA (
  p_cedula    IN  VARCHAR2,
  p_resultado OUT VARCHAR2
) 
AS
  v_text VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
  v_text := REGEXP_REPLACE(p_cedula, '[^0-9E]');
  p_resultado := LTRIM(SUBSTR(v_text, 1, LENGTH(v_text) - 10), '0')
              || LTRIM(SUBSTR(v_text, LENGTH(v_text) - 9, 4), '0')
              || LTRIM(SUBSTR(v_text, -6), '0');
END AGAITAN_PROCESAR_CEDULA;
/

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (input, expected) AS
SELECT '09N 0720001536',  '97201536' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '08N 0798001682',  '87981682' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '08NT0184001825',  '81841825' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '05NT0702001350',  '57021350' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  '08 0732001283',  '87321283' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '00E 0008138007',  'E8138007' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  '10 0732001283', '107321283' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '10N 0798001682', '107981682' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '10NT0702001350', '107021350' FROM DUAL;

Then calling the procedure for each row of the sample data:
DECLARE
  v_text TABLE_NAME.EXPECTED%TYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT * FROM table_name) LOOP
    AGAITAN_PROCESAR_CEDULA(r.input, v_text);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
      r.input
      || ' => ' || v_text
      || ': ' || CASE WHEN v_text = r.expected THEN 'Match' ELSE 'No Match' END
    );
  END LOOP;
END;
/

Outputs:
09N 0720001536 => 97201536: Match
08N 0798001682 => 87981682: Match
08NT0184001825 => 81841825: Match
05NT0702001350 => 57021350: Match
08 0732001283 => 87321283: Match
00E 0008138007 => E8138007: Match
10 0732001283 => 107321283: Match
10N 0798001682 => 107981682: Match
10NT0702001350 => 107021350: Match

fiddle
