# Oracle - getting 'value too large' error while inserting data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to insert northwind sample database in oracle 11g. While it worked mostly, for some insert queries i got below error -

> ORA-12899: value too large for column "SYSTEM"."CUSTOMERS"."CITY"
>   (actual: 16, maximum: 15)

The data looked like -

```
Insert into CUSTOMERS
   (CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_CODE, COMPANY_NAME, CONTACT_NAME, CONTACT_TITLE, ADDRESS, CITY, REGION, POSTAL_CODE, COUNTRY, PHONE, FAX)
 Values
   (35, 'HILAA', 'HILARIÃ“N-Abastos', 'Carlos HernÃ¡ndez', 'Sales Representative', 
    'Carrera 22 con Ave. Carlos Soublette #8-35', 'San CristÃ³bal', 'TÃ¡chira', '5022', 'Venezuela', 
    '(5) 555-1340', '(5) 555-1948');
```

Note the special Ã in city value. When i replaced that special character with normal A, it got inserted successfully.

```
Insert into CUSTOMERS
   (CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_CODE, COMPANY_NAME, CONTACT_NAME, CONTACT_TITLE, ADDRESS, CITY, REGION, POSTAL_CODE, COUNTRY, PHONE, FAX)
 Values
   (35, 'HILAA', 'HILARIÃ“N-Abastos', 'Carlos HernÃ¡ndez', 'Sales Representative', 
    'Carrera 22 con Ave. Carlos Soublette #8-35', 'San CristA³bal', 'TÃ¡chira', '5022', 'Venezuela', 
    '(5) 555-1340', '(5) 555-1948');
```

I didnt reduced the number of characters. When length of data was not changed, why oracle gives such an error?

Comment: You have encoding problems, the data you're showing is corrupt (UTF-8 interpreted as ASCII it looks like).

Comment: Create a new user for your CUSTOMERS table, you should not be touching the SYSTEM or SYS schemas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I didn't reduced the number of characters. When length of data was not
>   changed, why oracle gives such an error?

Because **`number of characters not always = no of bytes`** .
When the database character set is UTF-8 ( generally true ),some characters take more than 1 byte to store in the database.

To verify this, you may use functions `LENGTH`, which gives character length  and `LENGTHB` which gives you bytes length.

```
SELECT
    length('A'),
    length('Ã'),
    lengthb('A'),
    lengthb('Ã')
FROM
    dual;

LENGTH('A') LENGTH('Ã') LENGTHB('A') LENGTHB('Ã')
----------- ----------- ------------ ------------
          1           1            1            2
```

So, If have defined the column as `VARCHAR2( n BYTE)` and not `VARCHAR2( n CHAR)`, then this error will be raised, when you try to insert a n character string, which takes more than 1 byte per character, like `Ã`

As an example consider this

```
create table test_byte( c VARCHAR2(1 byte) );
INSERT INTO test_byte(c) VALUES('Ã');

ORA-12899: value too large for column "HR"."TEST_BYTE"."C" (actual: 2,
maximum: 1)
```

However, if I specify the column as `1 CHAR`, the insert works.

```
create table test_byte2( c VARCHAR2(1 char) );
INSERT INTO test_byte2(c) VALUES('Ã');
1 row inserted.
```

Refer this question for further details : [Difference between BYTE and CHAR in column datatypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81448/difference-between-byte-and-char-in-column-datatypes)