# ORA-1458 : invalid length inside variable character string,ORA-01483: invalid length for DATE or NUMBER bind variable

Tags: oracle12c, oracleforms

we have been trying to solve an issue for quite sometime now.We are currently in the middle of an oracle version upgrade(RMS12 application) from 11g to 12c including forms and reports as well.We have been noticing some very strange behaviour in some of the forms,that is whenever we perform some update or insert operation from the form we get ora-01458 and ora-01483 errors.Strange thing is that these errors doesn't occur in the lower version 11g.

Any input will be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: This is just a suspicion: are your text columns defined with a maximum number of chars or bytes? If you have changed charset or the default setting of bytes vs chars in `varchar2(x)` while upgrading. In UTF-8 characters use 1-4 bytes. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81448/difference-between-byte-and-char-in-column-datatypes

Comment: Are you sure you've recompiled everything you need to?

Comment: The text columns are defined with a max.of bytes @Kjetli